# One of my class's imagefield not relative to Media

Tags: django, model, relative-path, django-models

Something odd is happening, after i modified my models Imagefield names one of the class is not returning the URL relative to media.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Contact(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    description = models.TextField(null = True)
    poste = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photo", null=True)
    photo_description = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)
    hire_date = models.DateTimeField(null = True)

    def __str__ (self):
        return  self.nom

class Partner(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    website = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    mail = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    description = models.TextField(null = True)
    partner_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="partner_logo", null=True)
    partner_logo_description = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)
    parternship_date = models.DateTimeField(null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom

class PressArticle(models.Model):
    titre = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    website = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    mail = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    description = models.TextField(null = True)
    article_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="article_photo", null=True)
    article_photo_description = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)
    article_date = models.DateTimeField(null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titre
```

**Working template**

```
{% extends "base.html"%}
    {%block content %}
        <div class="container">
        <p>partner page</p>
        {% for partner in partners %}

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img width="200"height="150"  src ="{{partner.partner_logo.url}}" title="{{partner.partner_logo_description}}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h3 style="margin-top:0px">{{partner.prenom}} {{partner.nom}}</h3> - <small>{{partner.poste}}</small>
                    <p>
                    {{partner.description}}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </br>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

**Not working Template**

```
{% extends "base.html"%}
    {%block content %}
        <div class="container">
        <p>Press page</p>
        {% for article in articles %}

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img  src ="{{article.article_photo}}" title="{{article.article_photo_description}}" width="200"height="150">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h3 style="margin-top:0px">{{article.titre}}</h3> - <small>{{article.article_date}}</small>
                    <p>
                    {{article.description}}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </br>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

So it seems there are no difference between those templates. one is displaying **PressArticle** the other **Partner**
When i look at the html generated i have:

```
<img  src ="article_photo/newspapers.jpg" title="placeholder" width="200"height="150">
```

and the working one :

```
<img width="200"height="150"  src ="/media/partner_logo/partener.jpg" title="placeholder">
```

SO what could be the problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
<img  src ="{{article.article_photo.url}}"...>
```

instead of:

```
<img  src ="{{article.article_photo}}"...>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the database is saved the relative path, so you need to write the `MEDIA_URL` as well in your template:

```
<img  src ="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{article.article_photo}}" title="placeholder" width="200"height="150">
```